# CSS not loading on page

Tags: html, css

first time on Stack Overflow. I have been self teaching myself web design in the last few months or so. I have just started another website just for practice but the CSS doesn't seem to want to load.

I have been using Brackets to practice and when I am previewing the page in chrome it is only loading up with default styling.

Here is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lan="en">

<head>
<title>Monster Mash | Home</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
    
<body>

<header>
    
    <h1>Monster Mash | Home</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Classical</li>
        <li>Movies</li>
        <li>Mythological</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>

</header>

<h2>Welcome</h2>    
<p>Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla Bla bla bla bla bla</p>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

The only CSS I have currently linked to the page is:

```
p {
    background-color: green;
}
```

This is in a separate file named "styles.css"

So I am not sure why the styling isn't loading.

Comment: Is the path to your stylesheet correct?

Comment: is `styles.css` the name of your usually called `style.css`

Comment: OT: little typo in your code: `<html lan="en">` should be `<html lang="en">`

Comment: This code assumes styles.css and your html file are in the same directory. Is that the case?

Comment: Yeah they are both within the same folder.

Comment: Your HTML `lang` attribute is missing the letter 'g'

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser cache or reload without cache?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your css file is in the other folder, for example:
[css folder] -> [styles.css]
If it is, you have to change your path to css/styles.css
I see no other reason your css is not loading

Comment: while you are absolutely correct, I would suggest that a "maybe" can not be an "answer"

Comment: @Martin, i am agree with you. However, with <50 reputation you still can not post comment

Comment: @TienNguyen sorry, I had forgotten that issue. Overall, raises a bit of a(n off-topic) dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

To me it works fine. 
Maybe the css file is not in the proper location. According to your code it should be in the same folder as html file.
If it is in some other directory, link it to the proper directory.

Sorry, but it works perfectly fine with IE, Chrome and Firefox. Cannot understand your problem.
If you can give more information maybe we could help.

There could be just a naming error. Check it out.

Comment: My stylesheet is in the same folder, I am beginning to wonder if it is a setting in chrome or something.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your .html and your .css need to be in the same folder for this to work. Assuming your server is `http://localhost` and this is where your .html file resides, if you go to `http://localhost/styles.css` you should see the contents of your stylesheet.

Make sure to clear your browser cache to always get the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried copying your HTML & CSS. Everything exactly as you have described.

Turns out CSS is working 100% fine.

Here's a quick way to find out if your `styles.css` is linked properly. Open your HTML file, right-click and select similar to *View page source*. Once there, click `styles.css`. If it works fine, then stylesheet is linked properly.

Then there is probably a problem of browser. Try opening the file in some other browser.

Answer (score 0):

If style sheet is in the same folder (and named correctly) then you should call it absolutely as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
```

by preceeding the filename with a **/**

### PLEASE NOTE:

This will only apply if your webpage is on the internet and not local, thank you to IkoTikashi .

I would keep this up, to show you that when documents are online, referencing them without a preceeding slash  -- `/`-- will search the same directory, whereas with the slash it will search the *base* directory of the website.

Please also note that your `<html lang='en'>` element is missing the letter 'g' which may cause various browser errors.

Comment: Only if he's using a webserver and not viewing the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your stylesheet is in the same location as your html document and the name of the stylesheet is correct.

If your stylesheet is in another folder then the path has to be relative to the document you are trying to link it to.

e.g. if you have a structure of

```
 - index.html
 - style
      - styles.css
```

then you need to use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I have fixed my problem.

```
<!-- CSS -->

p {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I messed up the comment at the top of my CSS, I took it out and now it works. I think I was getting my syntax for HTML and CSS comments mixed up. Thanks for all the help everyone :)